# Click for appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html like this:

```
<a class="link">text</a>
<div class="items"></div>

(function($) {

  var link = $('.link');
  link.click(function(){
    alert('it works!');
  });

  $('.items').each(function() {
    var items = $(this),
        item = $('<div>something inside</div>');

    items.append(item);
    item.click(link.click());
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I'm trying to bind a `click` event for an appended `item`. So when we click on `item`, `link` should be launched.

But I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'` from somewhere inside of jQuery.

Whats wrong?

Comment: This error is coming from somewhere else, you have no apply() inside your code and this code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UkGKh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `event delegation` to the dynamically added element:

```
items.on('click', item, function(){
     link.click();
});
```

### tryout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qQLLL/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try smth. like this:

```
function myClick(){
  alert('it works!');
}

$(".link").click(myClick);

$('.items').each(function() {
  var items = $(this),
      item = $('<div>something inside</div>');

  items.append(item);
  item.click(myClick);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try on event delegation

```
 items.on('click', item, function(){
    link.click();
 });
```

go through the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) if you want to read more about on event delegation

Comment: yeah... +1 for u then ... :) :).. for beign faster.. hehe :p

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(function($) {
    var handleClick = function() {
        alert('it works!');
    };
    $('.link').click(handleClick);
    $('<div>something inside</div>').appendTo('.items').click(handleClick);
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is :

```
item.click(link.click);
```

should be

```
item.click(function(){ link.click() });
```